# Transforming list of (characters+numbers) into simple string in python. How?

Tags: python

I am making a python program in which i have to list consist of characters and numbers and i have to concatenate these characters and numbers to make a string
e.g `['s','m','a','r','t','1','2','3']` should be `smart123`. 
It is not working it gives me error of type but I am confused about where is the type error. There is same list type . I am using `**for**` loop for this.
My code is:

```
list = ['s','m','a','r','t',1,2,3]
s = ""
for i in list:
    s += i
print(s)
```

Comment: is it `['s','m','a','r','t','1','2','3'] ` or `['s','m','a','r','t',1,2,3]`? There's a difference in between.

Comment: Yes ,there is differece in both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join()`:

```
list_ = ['s','m','a','r','t',1,2,3]
joined = ''.join([str(x) for x in list_])
print(joined)
# smart123
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `join()` method :

```
list=['s','m','a','r','t',1,2,3]
s = "".join([str(k) for k in list])
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
s = 'smart123'
```

**NOTE** :
A pythonic way would be not to assign any variable name as `list`.

Answer (score 2):

For resolving your type error:

```
list=['s','m','a','r','t',1,2,3]
s="" 
for i in list: 
    s+=str(i)
    print(s)
```

You get type error because you are appending a number to a string. So first, you need to convert number into str and then append it.

Additionally, you can skip for loop and try `''.join()`

```
list = ['s','m','a','r','t',1, 2, 3] 
s = ''.join([str(i) for i in list])
```

Lastly, `list` is a special keyword in python so never use only `list` as name for a list.